# LINQPad exception when using AI Assistant behind Proxy

Tags: linqpad, azure-openai

When using LINQPad, no matter if V7 or V8, AI Assistant with Provider Microsoft Azure I keep getting a `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException` with message

> The proxy tunnel request to proxy 'http://....:8080/' failed with
> status code '502

Our corporate proxy requires integrated authentication with AD account. Other LINQPad features which use networking, like NuGet package download, are working.

In LINQPad scripts I can enable this the authentication with:

```cs
// Configure default proxy credentials
HttpClient.DefaultProxy = new WebProxy
{
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
};
```

How to achieve this for the AI Assistant connection?